# What is better way of transmitting password input? Plaintext or its hash value?

Tags: hash

Let's just say there is a client and a server. The end-user inputs his/her password in the client interface. Then the data will be sent to the server for validation.

In terms of security, would it be best to:

- Transmit the plaintext password to the server? or
- Transmit the hash value of the plaintext to the server?

Comment: I just read it and yeap it's a duplicate... but it also solved my problem, which is nice! Thanks @Xander